# My app has been published in App Store,whether crashes in AppDelegate be send to Apple or not?

Tags: ios, crash, analysis

People who installed my app crashed when they open it,the crashes is likely in AppDelegate,would this crashes been sent to Apple Developer-->iTunes Connect -->APP Analysis?

Answer (score 0):

The crashes will appear there, but only if the users agreed to share the crash data.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html

> Apple provides a service that allows you to download crash reports for
>   the most recent app versions and builds that you distribute through
>   the store. The service collects and groups similar crash logs into
>   crash reports. Each build of an app may have multiple crash reports
>   and each crash report may contain multiple crash logs. However, crash
>   logs are not sent to Apple unless the user agrees to share crash data
>   with app developers. TestFlight users automatically agree to share
>   crash data.

Comment: Thankyou.Someone installed my app, they told me that they can not open it,their devices include iPhone 5s,iPhone6.But actually we have tested our app on iPhone 6 iOS 8.1 and iPhone 5s,under different network circumstance,WiFi,3G,2G,4G, we cannot reproduce the crash,what would the problem likely be?This problem has puzzled me a few days.